# How to apply css to particular label of text field in Internet explorer

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

Hello I am using ninja form and form is showing well in Mozilla Firefox and Google

chrome but it is not showing properly in Internet explorer last field label is

not not showing properly how to resolved this issue.

[here is link](https://manresa-sj.com/publication-form/)

[image]

the last field is **Email List Preferences (To choose multiple lists, press shift and click)** this field showing well in other browser.

Comment: In my `IE 11.576.14393.0` its working fine like other browsers.

Comment: But how to resolve this for  old browser

Comment: try to add to label css max-width attribute. e.g. `.label-left .nf-field-label label { width: 100%; display: inline-block; max-width: 100%;}` It should work on old IE

Comment: @Banzay thanks it is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `max-width` attribute to label css style.

```
.label-left .nf-field-label label {
   width: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

It should work on old IE